# Typo3 styles.content.getLeft

Tags: typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

actually i work on a typo3 template on Typo 7.6.12.
My Problem is that I am not able to get my content from the columns Left, Right or Border. Only normal is working.

My idea is, that the user can edit a footer-element on the left column and the basic content on the normal column.

Thats my code:

```
...
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
file = fileadmin/templates/gtstemplate/index.html
layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/gtstemplate/layouts/
partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/gtstemplate/html/partials/

variables {
    content < styles.content.get

    footer < styles.content.getLeft
    footer.slide = -1
  }
}
...
```

and my html code.

```
<div id="containerStart" class="container">
    <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="">{content}</f:format.html>
</div>

<footer>
  <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="">{footer}</f:format.html>
  <f:debug title="Results of customers query">{footer}</f:debug>
</footer>
```

With footer.slide = -1 i want the footer module to be inherited on all pages.

It's really confusing, cause the normal column is working with any problems, if I use the modules on it. But any other column isn't working.
The Debug puts a NULL out. With older Typo3 versions it worked without problems

CSS Content is included.

Would be cool if someone has any idea.
The Best ans thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you included *css_styled_content* or *fluid_styled_content*? *fluid_styled_content* is the state-of-the-art extension, widely compatible to *css_styled_content*.

*fluid_styled_content* has **no** *getLeft* component! You can easily define it yourself:

```
styles.content {
  getLeft < .get
  getLeft.select.where = colPos = 1
}
```

Use the TypoScript Object Browser to examine the *styles* component for details.

Comment: Its worse to mention, that even css_styled_content in Version 8.7 dropped that. So even if you still use css_styled_content with TYPO3 8 LTS you have to use this solution.